# Laravel. Where Should I put CSS files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I put file name style.css in {Laravel_project}/public/css/

I included in blade file like this.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" >
```

and then checked its source on browser.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/css/style.css" >
```

the file doesn't exist.
404
Not Found

Laravel version

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 7.11.0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No typos or anything in the filename?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the error?

Comment: have you tried with `{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}`

Comment: There seem no typos.

Comment: I am very sorry...typo caused the error.. the CSS file name was styles.css.